# Как объединить два FileInfo?

Tags: c#

Имеется следующий код:

```
var file1 = new FileInfo("tempDir");
var file2 = new FileInfo("D:\\");
```

Пытаюсь объединить в один путь, однако не совсем выходит

```
var rez = file1+file2;
```

Такой вариант не выходит. Как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: что значит _объединить в один путь_?

Comment: Лучше напишите что вы хотите сделать таким способом? Потому что `FileInfo` вы явно не по назначению используете, не предназначен этот класс для работы с каталогами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) - предоставляет свойства и методы экземпляра для создания,
>   копирования, удаления, перемещения и открытия файлов, а также
>   позволяет создавать объекты FileStream.

В Вашем случае логичнее вынести путь в переменную:

```
var filePath1 = @"tempDir";
var filePath2 = @"D:\";
var file1 = new FileInfo(filePath1);
var file2 = new FileInfo(filePath2);
// в таком случае не будет ошибки    
var rez = filePath2 + filePath1; // D:\\tempDir
```

Согласно примеру с MSDN ([FileInfo - конструктор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)), передают путь в качестве переменной в таком виде:

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var file1 = new FileInfo("tempDir");
var file2 = new FileInfo("D:\\" + file1);
```

Comment: А если пути не складываются (всмысле, оба полные абсолютные), как оно себя поведёт вообще? По моему, подозрительный код.

Comment: @Monk ну изначально был очень странный вопрос, больше похоже на троллинг, но код работает так как хотел Radzhab в конкретном примере

Comment: @DenisBubnov для конкретного примера код рабочий, я проверил, там валидация имени немного странная, поэтому конкретный пример исключениями не кидается. Но в целом ответ соответствует  вопросу по абсурдности. Т.к. это рухнет с исключением при любом обращении к методам `FileInfo`

Comment: @DenisBubnov =Р

Comment: Хм... валидация более чем странная... не удивительно что пропускает такое... для интересующихся http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,4ee673c1a4ecad41